# How to pass a label as an extra callback function argument

Tags: gtk, gtk3

So, here's my code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void buttonCall(GtkWidget * widget1, GtkWidget * widget2){//gpointer data){

gtk_label_set_text(*label,"some other label");

}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

GtkWidget * window;
GtkWidget * frame;
GtkWidget * button;
GtkWidget * label;

gtk_init(&argc,&argv);

window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
frame = gtk_fixed_new();

gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),frame);


button = gtk_button_new_with_label("button");
label = gtk_label_new("some label");

gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(frame),label);
gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(frame), label, 10,50);

gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(frame),button);
gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(frame), button, 10,100);

g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button),"clicked",G_CALLBACK(buttonCall),&label);

gtk_widget_show_all(window);

gtk_main();
return 0;
}
```

I basically want to click on a button and change the text on my label. I thought that by passing the address of label I'd be able to do that, however it isn't working. Is my implementation incorrect?

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That code doesn't even compile, right? That typically means the implementation is not correct. You are now making us do the debugging for you: if you don't understand the compile errors, at least paste them in the question. If something is "not working", you need to say exactly what is failing.

Now, label is already a pointer in `main()` so you don't need to get the address for `g_signal_connect()`: just remove the '&' from '&label'. In the clicked handler your second argument is called widget2 so that's what you need to use inside the function:

```
gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(widget2),"some other label");
```

That should make the code work, but I'll give another piece of advice: using GtkFixed is a bad idea in almost every case: Learn to do box layouts with GtkGrid (if your GTK version has it) or GtkBoxes, it will pay out in the end.